# How to determine if second-hand computer has been overclocked by previous owner?

Tags: windows-8, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, overclocking

I purchased my PC a few years back from a "hobbyist" who assembles gaming PCs and sells them on the internet marketplace Craigslist.

The computer has always worked great until recently, when the following recurring, yet unpredictable bug, began:

Both monitors of the computer will turn black, but the LED lights on the computer stay on, and no further responses come from the computer. Pressing the hard reset button makes the computer reset, but sometimes it will choke and turn off and on 3-4 times before starting.

Sometimes the bug will happen after 5 minutes of being turned on, and sometimes it will work for hours at high load with no issues. The bug often occurs with no significant drain on the resources (no games running, no video being processed.)

This issue started about 5-6 days ago and did not accompany any known software or hardware update.

[image]

Investigating this online, these seem to be the symptoms of an overclocked GPU. I downloaded a system diagnostic tool and here's what I found:

[image]

Unfortunately, this is where my luck runs out, since I have two problems:

1. How do I determine if these numbers are regular or represent "overclocked" hardware?
2. How do I reset this hardware to safe, or default levels?

And, as an aside,

3. If you do not think that a GPU would cause the problems mentioned, what would, and how can a hardware administrator correct the issue?

Crash Dump Info:
[image]

Reliability Monitor Info:
[image]

Notes:
There are no logs in the EventViewer for about 10 minutes before each crash.

Comment: Looking at the default clocks [here](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-570/specifications), it appears that it is indeed overclocked.

Comment: @TheKB! Thank you for the answer. The link is much appreciated. Could you maybe elucidate how you came to this conclusion in an answer? I'm looking at the link, and as someone who doesn't know much about overclocking, I wouldn't be able to tell you from the standard numbers which are important and what the corresponding values are.

Comment: If it's been working for years then it's not a firmware issue.

Comment: you can use hwinfo64

Answer (score 2):

1. According to [this](http://www.evga.com/articles/00596/), it is overclocked, but if it's an EVGA card (look at the card itself to see who made it), it could be overclocked at the factory, so it should be designed to handle this overclocking.
2. You typically can change the clock settings by going into your GPU driver settings. It might be under "Device Settings", "Performance", or "Clock Settings"

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer! Do you have any comment on the nature of the bug, and if it fits this line of reasoning?

Comment: Also, how can you tell by looking at a card who made it? (The computer that the issue is about has a see-through side, and the card is visible)

Comment: Look in the "System" log in the Event Viewer. Are there any errors that occur during the same time as the crash? For the GPU, what words do you see on the card?

Comment: Hey @helloworld111!
Thanks for the question.
The system log has lots of interesting errors and warnings, but nothing related to the GPU. Is there a way to output the system log info to be consumed by this forum?
Regarding the card, in addition to the regular serial numbers, the word PALIT is on the bottom

Comment: PALIT cards seem to have lower clock rates according to [this](http://www.palit.com/palit/vgapro.php?id=1450&lang=en&pn=NE5X570010DA-1101F&tab=sp), so your card is overclocked. Try reducing the memory clock to 1900MhZ & your GPU core clock to 732MhZ. If that doesn't work, try running the Memory Diagnostic (search for "Memory" on your computer to find it) for a few hours and tell us what it returns.

Comment: Sounds good. Just a note to anyone reading that if you don't see the setting in nVidia Control Panel, go to Performance > And choose "Accept"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to determine if a computer is overclocked

1. Download Open Hardware Monitor - http://openhardwaremonitor.org/
2. Look at the values registered by the Graphics Card / RAM / Processor and compare them to the value listed on the manufacturer's site.

Second, what is this bug?

This bug was caused by probably a bad sensor on the Graphics Card which was causing the temperature to register as lower than it was. As a result, the fan would not run and the card would overheat. In addition, the fan had gotten very clogged with dust over the years and the card was regularly exceeding 50 degrees celcius.

Since the monitors turning off was the first characteristic of the crash, it should have been a hint the graphics card was the problem.

I replaced my GTX 560 with an ASUS GTX 750TI, which is quieter and has a slightly smaller form factor, and the crashes stopped.

### tldr

The only way to solve this bug is to swap the GTX 560 graphics card with any compatible card (e.g., an ASUS GTX 750Ti) and see if the crashes stop.